# SystemVerilog Delay Interruption

Tags: verilog, variable-assignment, delay, system-verilog, interrupt

[image]

I have a question, hopefully somebody can help me.

In systemVerilog I have an input "en" and an output signal "en_delayed". The signals are not necessarily ports, they can be internal variables.

I want to apply a different delay to the signal when rising and when falling, like this:

```
timeunit              1ns;
timeprecision         1ps;

parameter   real    delay_en_rising_us  = 100.0;    // means 100us
parameter   real    delay_en_falling_us = 300.0;    // means 300us

assign  #(delay_en_rising_us*1.0e3, delay_en_falling_us*1.0e3)  en_delayed = en;
```

This is working fine as shown in picture 1.

But now, if I change the value of the delays like this

```
parameter   real    delay_en_rising_us  = 4000.0;   // means 4ms
parameter   real    delay_en_falling_us = 300.0;    // means 300us
```

then the falling edge is "masked" by the 4ms delay when the signal rises. See picture 2.

I want the "en_delayed" to react when "en" goes down i.e. force the signal "en_delayed" to go down 300us after "en" goes down.
The same behavior applies to the rising edges.

How can I avoid to this?

Content is already in the message.

---- UPDATE 1 ----

Thank you very much dave_59. This helped to solve the issue at the beginning.

However I see other problem with respect to what I want to implement. I included the modified code here for easy simulation.

As you can see in the attached picture we see the falling delay of 300us (red color interval) at "en_delayed" which is ok.

Then the signal "en" rises and we see the rising delay of 4000us (purple color interval) at "en_delayed" which is not ok because just before the 4000us rising delay completed there was an "en" signal going down, which should immediately cancel that previous rising delay of 4000us i.e. the signal "en_delayed" should not go high.

Then we see the signal "en_delayed" going down 300us after "en" goes down (yellow color interval) which is not ok, because the signal "en_delayed" should have stayed low. Besides that, the next rising edge of "en" should immediately cancel the uncompleted falling delay of 300us at "en_delayed" (in case there was an uncompleted valid one).

Then we see the signal "en_delayed" go high with a rising delay of 4000us (blue color interval) which is ok.

In summary, the signal en_delayed should not be going up and down around 7000us (white circled region).

I hope that I could explain correctly. Actually the idea is that if there is a delay which has not completed and the signal "en" suddenly changes, then that uncompleted delay should be immediately discarded.

Thank you!

[image]

```
module top;
  timeunit            1ns;
  timeprecision         1ps;
  parameter   real    delay_en_rising_us  = 4000.0;    // means 4ms
  parameter   real    delay_en_falling_us = 300.0;    // means 300us
  logic en;
  logic en_delayed;
  
  always_comb
    if ($realtime == 0)
      en_delayed = en;
    else if (en)
      en_delayed <= #(delay_en_rising_us*1us) en;
    else
      en_delayed <= #(delay_en_falling_us*1us) en;
  
  //initial begin
  initial fork
    $dumpfile("dump.vcd"); $dumpvars;
    en = 1;
    #1000us en = 0; // or add a bigger delay past 4ms
    #3000us en = 1;
    #6900us en = 0;
    #7100us en = 1;
    #15000us $finish;
  //end
  join
endmodule
```

Comment: is there a reproducer with a test bench?  I suspect that 'en' changes from 0 to 1 quicker than the delay from the previous action (which is undefined behavior). Note that change from 'x' to '0' is also controlled by the second delay parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you are forgetting about the first rising edge of `en` at time 0. `en_delayed` will not *rise* to 1 until 4ms. You are changing `en` to 1 at time 0 and then back  to 0 at 1000us before `en_delayed` has a chance to be set to 1.

To get your desired behavior, you can either change the timing of your stimulus, or write some behavioral code to take it. Note that a continuous assignment cannot change the LHS faster than the delay specified on the RHS. This is known as an *inertial delay model*. You can use nonblocking assignments to implement a *transport delay model*.

```
module top;
  timeunit            1ns;
  timeprecision         1ps;
  parameter   real    delay_en_rising_us  = 4000.0;    // means 4ms
  parameter   real    delay_en_falling_us = 300.0;    // means 300us
  logic en;
  logic en_delayed;
  
  always_comb
    if ($realtime == 0)
      en_delayed = en;
    else if (en)
      en_delayed <= #(delay_en_rising_us*1us) en;
    else
      en_delayed <= #(delay_en_falling_us*1us) en;
  
  initial begin
    $dumpfile("dump.vcd"); $dumpvars;
    en = 1;
    #1000us en = 0; // or add a bigger delay past 4ms
    #2000us en = 1;
    #5000us en = 0;
  end
endmodule
```

Comment: Thank you very much dave_59. I added an update with additional information after implementing your suggestion. Please have a look and if possible give me feedback. Thank you!